# how to fully shutdown audio input stream

Tags: web-audio-api

I have created an audio worklet that performs pitch detection , all works fine but I want to free the microphone once I am done

I get the stream and wire everything up like this

```
        const AudioContextConstructor =
            window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        this.audioContext = new AudioContextConstructor();

        await this.audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('js/worklet_pitcher.js');
        this.stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });

        var mediaStreamSource = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.stream);
        this.pitchWorklet = new AudioWorkletNode(this.audioContext, 'pitch-processor');
        mediaStreamSource.connect(this.pitchWorklet);
```

When I am done I simply do this

```
stop = (): void => {
     if (this.running) {
        this.audioContext.close();
        this.running = false;
    }
}
```

this stops the worklet pipeline but the red dot still shows in the browser tab meaning that I still own the mic.

I looked for a `stream.close` so I could explicitly close the `MediaStream` returned by `getUserMedia`but there isnt one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to call `stop()` on each `MediaStreamTrack` of the `MediaStream` obtained from the mic.

```
this.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/getTracks

Comment: ty v much......